# Why can't I create a leveldb with current user home directory path? It was successful when I switch to the path starting with the root directory

Tags: c++, linux, database, leveldb

The program shown below would run correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glog/logging.h>
#include "leveldb/db.h"
#include "leveldb/filter_policy.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    leveldb::DB *db;
    leveldb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "/mnt/nvme/test", &db);
    std::cout<<status.ToString()<<std::endl;
    assert(status.ok());
    return 0;
}
```

But if line 12 changed to this, it will not work.

```
leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "~/whatever/db", &db);
```

The error message is:

```
NotFound: ~/whatever/db/LOCK: No such file or directory
test_leveldb: /testdb/src/test/test_leveldb.cc:14: int main(): Assertion `status.ok()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The directory '~/whatever/db' exists but I don't know why it didn't work.
Does anyone have had this problem or know why? Thanks.

Comment: `~` is a shortcut a shell expands into an actual path, and your program needs to do the same. Look up the current users home directory and replace `~` with the actual path.

Comment: `~` is probably not a valid directory name. Did you expect anyone (like the shell) to replace that with the content of the `HOME` environment variable perhaps?